# How to use dictionary keys and values in python Class?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new and try to learn class method in python. 
I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
d = {
    "day_rate":None,
    "hourly_rate": 50,
    "Comp_ID":[482,483],
    "availability":"",
    "page": 1
}

ans = {
        "hourly_rate": "50",
        "day_rate":None, 
         "available": "Available Immediately", 
         "competencies": "485,483,488"
      }
```

Now I want to insert this two dictionaries in python class and want to use their keys in class function.
I tried in simple way like I just insert dict and try to use directly.
My approach as follows:

```
class employer_search(object):

    def __init__(self,ans,d):
        self.ans = ans
        self.d = d

        print(ans)
        print(d)

    def Competency_scoring(self):
        if self.ans['competencies'] is not None:
            Job_comp = []
            for i in (self.ans['competencies'].split(",")):
                Job_comp.append(int(i))
            h = []
            for j in self.d['Comp_ID']:
                for i in Job_comp:
                    if j == i: 
                        a = i
                        h.append(a)
            matched_comp = []
            final_result = []

            q = [[x,h.count(x)] for x in set(h)]

            print(len(q))

            if len(q) == 1:
                comp_score = 0.25
            elif len(q) == 2:
                comp_score = 0.50
            elif len(q) == 3:
                comp_score = 0.75
            elif len(q) >= 4:
                comp_Score = 1.0
            return(comp_score)
        else:
            return(0)
```

then I did

```
es = employer_search(d,ans)
es.Competency_scoring()
```

it gives me keyerror of dict key. Error is follows:

```
KeyError: 'competencies'
```

I tried to correct key name but it gives me error continuesly.
Can anyone please help me how to use dictionary keys in Python class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing function argument in wrong order:

Here,

```
es = employer_search(d,ans)
```

should be

```
es = employer_search(ans,d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It resolved. Appreciate you answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are getting is [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) which **is raised when  a mapping (dictionary) key is not found** in the set of existing keys. In your case the `competencies` key is not in dict `d`.

So, you'll need to change your class call from:

`es = employer_search(d,ans)`

To:

`es = employer_search(ans,d)`

Side note:

- You can make `__init__` call mandatory using named parameter by writing it as:
  `def __init__(self,*,ans,d)` and then call it as `es = employer_search(ans=ans, d=d)`
- Also, if you are using Python 3 you can simply declare it as `class EmployerSearch:`. (CamelCase)